# android.py installsdk error

Tags: android, python, pygame

I am trying to make an android app with python's pygame and pgs4a. I am following [this](http://possiblywrong.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/python-on-android/)
tutorial and using windows.

When I try to run android.py installsdk I get the following error:

```
usage: android.py [-h] [--launch] command [argument [argument ...]]
android.py: error: too few arguments
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you need to call Python explicitly.  Change

```
android.py installsdk
```

to

```
python android.py installsdk
```

Comment: I don't see how this is different from the command you said was giving you the error.

Comment: the old command is 'android.py installsdk' the new command is 'python android.py installsdk'. on windows you need to call python otherwise it doesnt know what to do @cpburnz